# Linux Authentication by Active Directory without joining to domain

Tags: linux, active-directory, windows-server-2016

I need to authenticate some CentOS7 machines against an AD domain, but I cannot join my machines to this domain.

I can obtain kerberos tickets, but then I can't ssh my local machines using these domain accounts.

I've tried LDAP, but then again how can I login?

The server I have to reach is a Windows Server 2016 (so, no IDMU).

I need to never save users on these CentOSes.

Something I've tried:

- [PAMvsLDAPvsKERBEROS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334287/pam-vs-ldap-vs-sssd-vs-kerberos/334345)
- [Centos Auth without kerberos](http://htfdidt.blogspot.com/2014_06_01_archive.html)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand what you want to do. Open a plain Linux session then authenticate against a Windows server (say, to run a PowerShell script from Ansible, or to invoke a web service) using Kerberos credentials? Or delegate your Linux authentication/authorization to Active Directory (say, via SSSD with a mix of Kerberos for users & LDAP for groups)?

Comment: Unfortunately, the second one.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get CentOS 7 machines to authenticate users again our institute's AD without joining the domain with this command:

```
authconfig \
--enablekrb5 \
--krb5realm=YOUR_REALM \
--krb5kdc=your_ad_domain_controller \
--enablekrb5kdcdns \
--updateall
```

Users accounts are created on CentOS 7 machines with usernames matching the AD, and no need to set any passwords.  Hope it helps.